# neo4j query error "dont know how to compare"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, owl

I loaded Neo4j with Pizza.owl file using hermit reasoner and Java.
when i pass a simple query:

```
match (n) where n="name:Pizza" return n;
```

am getting the following error

```
 Don't know how to compare that. Left: Node[1]{name:"owl:Thing"} (NodeProxy); Right: "name:Pizza" (String)
```

Is NodeProxy a datatype? How can I make both of them to be compared. Can I do casting while querying? Any query to change datatype of the entire graph nodes? How to check the type of the node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing a node `n` to a string "name:Pizza", which doesn't make sense. What you want is to compare the property `name` of node `n` with the string "Pizza": `WHERE n.name = "Pizza"`. The whole query then looks like this

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name = "Pizza"
RETURN n
```

Nodes don't really have types. Take a look at the [Neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/) to more about [nodes, relationships, properties and labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/) and about [Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) in general, and the [`WHERE` clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html) in particular.

Comment: You're welcome! Please "accept" the answer so that it shows as "resolved" when others are searching/browsing questions.